# Bit manipulation golang

Tags: go, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm looking at a codebase with the following:

```
const IdLength = 20

type NodeID [IdLength]byte

func (node NodeID) PrefixLen() (ret int) {
  for i := 0; i < IdLength; i++ {
    for j := 0; j < 8; j++ {
      if (node[i] >> uint8(7 - j)) & 0x1 != 0 {
        return i * 8 + j;
      }
    }
  }
  return IdLength * 8 - 1;
}
```

I can't quite grasp what's happening here. Could someone explain it to me with an example?

Comment: Try printing the variables with binary formating for each loop iteration

Comment: The name of the function, `PrefixLen`, should give you a clue. It counts the length of the sequence's prefix, which in this case is a number of leading zero bits in 20 bytes. Also, it can be optimized by checking for zero bytes first, counting them as 8 zero bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This takes as input a variable number of bytes which are really treated as bits. It returns the number of leading `0` bits in the stream of bytes. Say you have these bytes:

```
0x00 0x00 0x05
```

which in binary looks like this

```
00000000 00000000 00000101
```

which means the function returns `8+8+5 = 21`.

The outer loop with `i` as the variable goes over all bytes, the inner loop with `j` as the variable goes over all bits in that byte. It shifts the jth bit from the top, down to the lowest bit, the binary and (`&`) with `0x01` masks all but that lowest bit, then `!= 0` asks if this bit is `1` in which case we are at the end of the `0` prefix and return the result.

If at the end of the function there was no early return, all bytes are `0` so it returns the value for that. That special case does not return 20*8 but 20*8-1 for some reason. This is specific to the application I guess. I would have expected it to return all zeros, but it returns one fewer.

Here is a code example with the outputs as comments:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(NodeID{0xFF}.PrefixLen()) // 0
    fmt.Println(NodeID{0x7F}.PrefixLen()) // 1
    fmt.Println(NodeID{0x3F}.PrefixLen()) // 2
    fmt.Println(NodeID{0x1F}.PrefixLen()) // 3
    fmt.Println(NodeID{0x0F}.PrefixLen()) // 4
    // ...
    fmt.Println(NodeID{0x00, 0x00, 0x05}.PrefixLen()) // 21
    // ...
    fmt.Println(NodeID{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}.PrefixLen()) // 159
    fmt.Println(NodeID{}.PrefixLen()) // 159
}

const IdLength = 20

type NodeID [IdLength]byte

func (node NodeID) PrefixLen() (ret int) {
    for i := 0; i < IdLength; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 8; j++ {
            if (node[i]>>uint8(7-j))&0x1 != 0 {
                return i*8 + j
            }
        }
    }
    return IdLength*8 - 1
}
```